# Считать CSV по строкам в Java

Tags: java, csv

Товарищи, подскажите, как считывать CSV-шник по строкам в Java?
Условие - не грузить файл в память BufferReader-ом.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше самому не читать, а пользоваться готовым [Opencsv](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/#what-is-opencsv), например.

```
au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader reader = new au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader(csvReader, charDelimiter, quoteChar, escapeChar, skipRows);
try {
    String[] nextLine;
    while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        getRow(nextLine);
    }
}
```